# How does one go about offering a mobile game, or offering all in-app purchases to backers?

Tags: android, game-maker, monetization, fund-raising

I am planning on trying to get my android game kickstarted. Of course, it's too early in development, and I will wait on until 60% done to do the kickstarter.

Some of the rewards I am hoping to give my backers are:

1. The android game without having to pay
2. All in-app purchases unlocked for them

Since the google Play store (or other market places) would be where I would put my game up, how would I be able to reward my backers?

I could give them an apk, but I would want them to enjoy the freedom of downloading from play store, getting automatic updates, re-installing whenever they want etc.

I am hoping some of you have done something similar and can shed some light on how one goes about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't released any games, but why not make it so your backers have to put in an email with a special code you send them? Your game will be attached to their accounts somehow and you will be able to achieve everything you just mentioned.

Comment: Yep, online game stores (Google Play, Steam, Origin, PSN, etc.) generally have a "redeem code" system by which you can give people free access to a game.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about this. Might be something I should look into.

These redeem codes work per game? I wouldn't want to give them a $2 play store code for them to go and buy something else :(

Comment: Well that would be pretty dumb of them to do, if they pledged to your Kickstarter. Why would you give these people a generic play store code? Couldn't you make it specific to your game?

Answer (score 0):

If you game is not out yet, check out itch.io. set your indie game up there, mobile users can download from itch.io. From creating a dev account on that site, you can send people product keys. You create a product key for each backer, and send the key to the person. they then activate this key and download from itch.io(Its free to upload to itch.io, as some mobile marketplaces it is not.But you can sell on itch.io as well, so use it to gain a fan-base, make some profits etc. Thats my advice) but if your going to splash the cash and upload it to Mobile Marketplaces, i can tell you from my experience that giving people codes is easier on android, but its still not a massive task on I-store(Cant for the love of me remember the correct name).

*summary*

Id advise you go on itch.io to upload as its a good starting platform for indie games both pc and mobile. If you do go with a store like Google play store etc then its still going to be easy, just recommending something to save you money :)
Hope i helped.

Comment: Both of my games i released through itch.io, so i know that the site is good for indie games, its a great place to start!

That being said, if you want to splash money out then the Phone markets like Google Play and Apples store thing are good, just cost money.

Comment: i just realized this is like 2 years old, but might be good advice for other new people wanting to sell.